# Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

I'm having an error that only happens to me. My colleagues don't get the same error and we share the same code.
I'm trying to pod install but I'm getting this error:

> Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end.

My pod version is: 1.5.3

Here is the link to my pod file: https://gist.github.com/brunocuratio/6240bcaf69adcfae5c9026086b466cb7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two `if` statements in the `post_install` hook seem to have their `end`s missing. This should work:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'NMessenger'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
            end
        end
        if target.name == 'Kingfisher'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
            end
        end
        if target.name == 'PopupDialog'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. but it is odd because for the other guys works and only for me doesn't work. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this error

`[!] Invalid` Podfile `file: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input.`
What worked for me was

1. I had removed the Podfile from the project folder which had an error and then
2. Opened and added all the necessary dependencies in the new Podfile, then
3. Did `pod install` on the terminal and the error had gone.

May work for some. Good luck !!

Answer (score -2):

Just delete the Podfile and build again. It should create a new one without any issues.

Comment: I don't think podfiles are recreated every time. Not on native iOS, at least